# Excel to Json getting file data into state in React JS

Tags: javascript, excel, json, react.js

I am using dropzone and XLSX to load excel documents and then convert them into json.

The goal is to upload as many documents as possible and it will create an object with a key of the file name and then the value as the data. The problem I notice is that reader.onload is not available immediately after calling readAsArrayBuffer(). My solution was to use setTimeout. I am wondering if there is another method that I might be able to use instead of setTimeout as though it works perfectly, I feel it is more of a hack and maybe something exists that I have not learned or just don't know well enough. Here is my code inside the react element.

```
const [showLoader, setShowLoader] = useState(false)
const [filePaths, setFilesPaths] = useState([]);
const [parsedData, setParsedData] = useState({})
const [validationErrors, setValidationErrors] = useState([])
const [fileTypeError, setFileTypeError] = useState("")
const [uploadError, setUploadError] = useState("")

const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
  setShowLoader(true)
  let data = {...parsedData};
  let files = [...filePaths];
  let errors = []

  if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
    setValidationErrors([])
  }

  if (fileTypeError) {
    setFileTypeError("")
  }

  if (uploadError) {
    setUploadError("")
  }

  acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
    reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
    reader.onload = () => {
      const isExcelFile = file.type === XLSX_MIME_TYPE

      if (!isExcelFile) {
        setFileTypeError("One or more of the files added were removed because they were not excel files");
        return;
      }

      if (filePaths.includes(file.path)) {
        setUploadError("One or more of the files wasn't added because a file of that name already exists");
        return
      }

      let bstr = reader.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'array', bookVBA : true, cellDates: true, cellStyles: true});
      /* Get first worksheet */
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      /* Convert array of arrays */
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

      const validateData = data.map(dataItem => {
        const validTypes = ["Major", "Patch", "Maint", "Dependency", "Infrastructure"]
        if (!dataItem["Application Description"] || !validTypes.includes(dataItem["Event Type"]) || !dataItem["Event Type"]) {
          return "error"
        } else {
          return "valid"
        }
      })

      if (validateData.includes("error")) {
        reader.errorMessage = "error";
      } else {
        reader.data = [...data].map((item, index) => {
          return {
            id: index,
            ...item
          }
        })
      }
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (reader.errorMessage) {
        errors.push(`${file.path} contains errors, please make sure it was filled out correctly`)
      } else {
        files.push(file.path)
        data[file.path] = reader.data
      }
    }, 250)
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      setValidationErrors(errors)
    }
    setFilesPaths(files)
    setParsedData(data)
    setShowLoader(false)
  }, 250)
}, [
  validationErrors,
  fileTypeError,
  uploadError,
  parsedData,
  filePaths
])
```

So in short the code isn't broken. I'm just curious if I am going about achieving the result that I want correctly. If not doing correctly or if a better method I would love to know and understand how that works. I appreciate everyones help.